# No catch block still execution continues without any warning or error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I am having this code. In `aMethod()` try block is there, but no catch block to handle the thrown exception. And the output generated is **finally exception finished**. Can anyone explain me how's this happening?

```
   public class Test 
    {  
        public static void aMethod() throws Exception 
        {
            try /* Line 5 */
            {
                throw new Exception(); /* Line 7 */
            } 
            finally /* Line 9 */
            {
                System.out.print("finally "); /* Line 11 */
            } 
        } 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            try 
            {
                aMethod();  
            } 
            catch (Exception e) /* Line 20 */
            {
                System.out.print("exception "); 
            } 
            System.out.print("finished"); /* Line 24 */
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `finally` block is always executed, exception or not<sup>*</sup>. That's what is causing the first printout `"finally"` that you see.
- Next, the uncaught exception propagates to `main`, where it gets caught in the `catch` block, producing `"exception"`.
- After that, your program prints `"finished"` to complete the output.

That is how `finally` works. Moreover, if you do this

```
try {
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    ...
}
```

the code in both `catch` and `finally` blocks would be executed.

<sup>*</sup> There are corner cases when you can construct a program that exits without executing a `finally` block, but it has nothing to do with the code in your example.

Comment: I am not agree with your first point **finally block is always executed, exception or not**. There may be possibility that finally block will never execute(not in this question).

Comment: Well i agree now. But let me clear one more thing. if there will be an unchecked exception in aMethod()'s try and still the catch block is absent. Now, output will be the same or something different?

Answer (score 1):

You declared `aMethod()` as  `throws Exception`, so it can throw any checked exception and doesn't have to catch anything.

Comment: Okay, but let me clarify if there will be an unchecked exception and still the catch block is absent. Now, what will be the output? Error or same as above.

Comment: @choxx For unchecked exceptions you never have to catch them regardless of any `throws` clause. The output will be the same.